# How to do alpha matting in python

Tags: python, image-processing

How to do alpha matting in python?

More specifically, how to extract the alpha channel of an image, given a trimap which marks pixels as either

- 100% foreground (white)
- 100% background (black)
- or unknown (gray)

### Input image

[image]

### Input trimap

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Using a library for alpha matting

Here are two options, both based on the paper ["A Closed Form Solution to Natural Image Matting"](http://webee.technion.ac.il/people/anat.levin/papers/Matting-Levin-Lischinski-Weiss-CVPR06.pdf) by Levin and Lischinski.

- https://github.com/MarcoForte/closed-form-matting
- https://github.com/99991/matting

### The math behind it

1. Calculate the matrix `L` based on image `I` which describes how similar neighboring pixels are:

[image: matrix L]

2. Solve the linear system for alpha using a constraint matrix `D` and vector `b` to fix the known alpha values:

[image: solve for alpha]

### Implementation in python

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg
import scipy.sparse
import scipy.sparse.linalg
from PIL import Image
from numba import njit

def main():
    # configure paths here
    image_path  = "cat_image.png"
    trimap_path = "cat_trimap.png"
    alpha_path  = "cat_alpha.png"
    cutout_path = "cat_cutout.png"

    # load and convert to [0, 1] range
    image  = np.array(Image.open( image_path).convert("RGB"))/255.0
    trimap = np.array(Image.open(trimap_path).convert(  "L"))/255.0

    # make matting laplacian
    i,j,v = closed_form_laplacian(image)
    h,w = trimap.shape
    L = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((v, (i, j)), shape=(w*h, w*h))

    # build linear system
    A, b = make_system(L, trimap)

    # solve sparse linear system
    print("solving linear system...")
    alpha = scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(A, b).reshape(h, w)

    # stack rgb and alpha
    cutout = np.concatenate([image, alpha[:, :, np.newaxis]], axis=2)

    # clip and convert to uint8 for PIL
    cutout = np.clip(cutout*255, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
    alpha  = np.clip( alpha*255, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

    # save and show
    Image.fromarray(alpha ).save( alpha_path)
    Image.fromarray(cutout).save(cutout_path)
    Image.fromarray(alpha ).show()
    Image.fromarray(cutout).show()

@njit
def closed_form_laplacian(image, epsilon=1e-7, r=1):
    h,w = image.shape[:2]
    window_area = (2*r + 1)**2
    n_vals = (w - 2*r)*(h - 2*r)*window_area**2
    k = 0
    # data for matting laplacian in coordinate form
    i = np.empty(n_vals, dtype=np.int32)
    j = np.empty(n_vals, dtype=np.int32)
    v = np.empty(n_vals, dtype=np.float64)

    # for each pixel of image
    for y in range(r, h - r):
        for x in range(r, w - r):

            # gather neighbors of current pixel in 3x3 window
            n = image[y-r:y+r+1, x-r:x+r+1]
            u = np.zeros(3)
            for p in range(3):
                u[p] = n[:, :, p].mean()
            c = n - u

            # calculate covariance matrix over color channels
            cov = np.zeros((3, 3))
            for p in range(3):
                for q in range(3):
                    cov[p, q] = np.mean(c[:, :, p]*c[:, :, q])

            # calculate inverse covariance of window
            inv_cov = np.linalg.inv(cov + epsilon/window_area * np.eye(3))

            # for each pair ((xi, yi), (xj, yj)) in a 3x3 window
            for dyi in range(2*r + 1):
                for dxi in range(2*r + 1):
                    for dyj in range(2*r + 1):
                        for dxj in range(2*r + 1):
                            i[k] = (x + dxi - r) + (y + dyi - r)*w
                            j[k] = (x + dxj - r) + (y + dyj - r)*w
                            temp = c[dyi, dxi].dot(inv_cov).dot(c[dyj, dxj])
                            v[k] = (1.0 if (i[k] == j[k]) else 0.0) - (1 + temp)/window_area
                            k += 1
        print("generating matting laplacian", y - r + 1, "/", h - 2*r)

    return i, j, v

def make_system(L, trimap, constraint_factor=100.0):
    # split trimap into foreground, background, known and unknown masks
    is_fg = (trimap > 0.9).flatten()
    is_bg = (trimap < 0.1).flatten()
    is_known = is_fg | is_bg
    is_unknown = ~is_known

    # diagonal matrix to constrain known alpha values
    d = is_known.astype(np.float64)
    D = scipy.sparse.diags(d)

    # combine constraints and graph laplacian
    A = constraint_factor*D + L
    # constrained values of known alpha values
    b = constraint_factor*is_fg.astype(np.float64)

    return A, b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Output alpha

[image: cat alpha]

### Output cutout

[image: cat cutout]

Comment: You answer your own question? Does this really belong here?

Comment: @ErikXIII There is a very similar question, but the accepted answer is not about what is academically known as alpha matting. Additionally, the author is not active anymore.

Comment: i don't see problem @ErikXIII doing that.

Comment: Even "worse". He should accept own answer once allowed.

Comment: @John how can one generate the trimap ?

Comment: @pratiklodha Trimaps are usually generated by hand, because the computer can't possibly know beforehand which object you want to extract from an image. But if you just want to extract a specific class of object, you could train a neural network on it.