# Refine the Edges of Foreground Object

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am Working on removing Background from images and replacing it with White or any other Color.
I have almost completed it using Deep Learning.
The problem i am having is that at some places edges of foreground object consist background color which is what i want to remove.
Is there a way that i could achieve this with OpenCV or PIL.
Or any method which i can use to solve this issue.

Sample images with Input and Output that i achieved is present [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLKKK.jpg)
If you see Images still have a background color at edges and specifically at hair part.

Please have a look and guide me to get rid of this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that the purpose of your segmentation is to select foregrounds and paste it to another image, similar to what photoshop or other image editors do.

Your montage will seem more realistic if you blend the alpha channel from the foreground and background images in some regions, most often the hair; this is called alpha blending or alpha matte.

Here are a few implementations and references for the algorithms.

[He, Kaiming, et al. "A global sampling method for alpha matting." In CVPR’11, pages 2049–2056, 2011.](https://github.com/atilimcetin/global-matting)

[Stackoverflow implementation of "A Closed-Form Solution to Natural Image Matting"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55353735/how-to-do-alpha-matting-in-python)

Comment: I have used deep learning for background removal...first it removes the background and makes it transparent than i add a white color to transparent background thats how it works.....so  now do i have to use the output image as input for the solution you provided or do i have to provide my input as it is

Comment: Most alpha blending methods receives the original image and a Trimap as input. You could perform some morphology operations to obtain the Trimap from the network output. So it would be a post-processing step.

Comment: ok....do you know for my problem how can i obtain trimap using input

Comment: Yes, with erosion and dilation of the output mask. https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html