# How do i remove the background of this type of images with black color?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I want to change image background  to black color. I tried with some codes but it didn't work, sometime it removes the object. The backgrounds in this images may vary depends on the places. with curiosity do I need to make machine learning to remove background for this kind of images for better results?

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image =  cv2.imread(r'D:/IMG_6334.JPG')
r = 150.0 / image.shape[1]
dim = (150, int(image.shape[0] * r))
resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
lower_white = np.array([80, 1, 1],np.uint8) #lower hsv value
upper_white = np.array([130, 255, 255],np.uint8) #upper hsv value
hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(resized,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) #rgb to hsv color space
#filter the background pixels
frame_threshed = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, lower_white, upper_white) 

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8) 
#dilate the resultant image to remove noises in the background
#Number of iterations and kernal size will depend on the backgound noises size
dilation = cv2.dilate(frame_threshed,kernel,iterations = 2)
resized[dilation==255] = (0,0,0) #convert background pixels to black color
cv2.imshow('res', resized)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a seperate topic on itself. Image matting is the thing you are looking for. This is used to convert your background to black and your foreground to white(which in this case you dont have to do). Check out this website http://alphamatting.com/ where all the state of the art matting algos are present and try implementing it in ur code. I would say this is really long route, so I can say better solution if you mention what exactly are you planning to do after removing the backgrounds of the image.

Comment: i don't want to change the  foreground to white, i just want to  replace the background things to black, iam  planning to detect the plant diseases using GLCM, 1st setup is to remove background the things from images and pump the image to color histogram and finally to check texture of the images

Comment: Yes, you can do that using a small change in ur alpha matting code. You can put a conditional loop statement saying whenever you find rgb value to be [0,0,0] (which means black), you dont do anything, and whenever you find a rgb value to be [255,255,255] (which means white), you put the original image's pixel value. By this method you are skipping through the black pixels and super imposing your original image pixels on your white pixel.

Comment: can i go with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55353735/how-to-do-alpha-matting-in-python ? am new to python. would be great if you can suggest  thanks

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was talking about. Check out that question, concise and on point.